# Storing Jenkins configuration for multiple environments

Tags: git, jenkins, integration-testing

My company uses Jenkins as an integration test executor.

We have multiple instances for our production and staging environments. The different environment need Jenkins configurations that are very similar, but have slight variations in things like periodic execution, notification, job enablement and so on.

Currently, we store the Jenkins configuration XML in Git, and make per-environment modifications as part of our Chef recipe while redeploying instances.

However, this means that it is very difficult to update an instance's configuration without redeploying it.

Does anyone have a favorite mechanism for sharing Jenkins configuration across different instances while applying small modifications per-instance?

Comment: The grace period of your bounty will expire in 10 hours. Can you assign the bounty or tell what is missing in the responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a multi-environment configfile with lines as

```
hostA:settings.xml:key_1:value_1A
hostB:settings.xml:key_1:value_1B
hostC:settings.xml:key_1:value_1C
hostD:settings.xml:key_1:value_1D

hostA:settings.xml:key_2:value_2A
hostB:settings.xml:key_2:value_2B
hostC:settings.xml:key_2:value_2C
hostD:settings.xml:key_2:value_2D
```

(above layout works when you do not need the : for key/values)

In your deployment script you call a post_configure script, that will select the correct host lines and replace the keys in the xml (keys found as `<key>...</key>`).
The code of the post_configure can be written in different languages.

Example
When all targets are Linux, and the start- and end-tag for each value is one 1 line, I would use bash and code something like

```
grep $(hostname) multi.cfg | while IFS=: read host file key value; do
   sed -i 's/'${key}'/'${value}'/g' ${file}
done
```

I believe this is a better approach than generating different distributions for the different systems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the [gradle-jenkins-plugin](https://github.com/ghale/gradle-jenkins-plugin/wiki) which basically extends the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) by allowing to maintain the job configurations in source control and apply them to a Jenkins server via Gradle. That way you can easily deploy the same configurations to different servers, with slight modifications using the DSL depending e.g. on the Jenkins server URL.

Alternatively, you could probably achieve something similar using the new [Workflow Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (not tested myself) would be to use the [Jenkins Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) through a wrapper like [`arangamani/jenkins_api_client`](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client) (ruby)

That would allow for [updating jobs](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client/blob/fb6a5b1fccbdbf4924bc7a595cc94992d38316cf/lib/jenkins_api_client/job.rb#L107-L126) of remote Jenkins instance, modifying only the parameters for which you need a small variation.